# Getting GRASS plugin working in QGIS for Windows?

Tags: qgis, qgis-grass-plugin

I've installed QGIS 2.16.3-1 on Windows 10 via the OSGeo4W 64-bit installer and also selected the following packages:

- grass (7.0.5-1)
- qgis-grass-plugin7 (2.16.3-1)
- qgis-grass-plugin-common (2.16.3-1)

I can't find the GRASS plugin in the list of plugins at **Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins > Installed (panel)**

And the QGIS Browser can see the grass location and mapset folder, but doesn't have the GRASS icon like it does in Linux. So layers can't be added to the map. I guess that means that the gdal-grass plugin is unavailable as well.

I tried launching **QGIS Desktop 2.16.3 with GRASS 7.0.4** but get the same results as above. Maybe the GRASS version mismatch is a problem or just a shortcut name typo.

Comment: Do you have an option in the Start Menu for 'QGIS  Desktop 2.16.3 with GRASS x.x.x'?

Comment: I just checked an OSGeo4W installed QGIS Desktop 2.16.3 with GRASS 7.0.5 on my machine. Maybe try to update

Comment: @underdark are you using 32-bit? Could be why obrl_soil's answer makes sense.

Comment: GRASS plugin is even not visible on the official repository: http://plugins.qgis.org/search/?q=GRASS how is that possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have this problem with the 64bit version. Grass 7.0.5 is a recent release, like less than a week. QGIS and the GRASS 7 plugin haven't been updated to catch up - e.g. if you look at the batch file launchers in \bin you'll see they all refer to 7.0.4.

What you need to do is launch the OSGeo4W setup, go to Advanced Install, navigate to the package list, and roll it back to 7.0.4. Until the rest of the package is updated, you should only install 7.0.5 if you're going to use it as a standalone app.

---

You can also uninstall qgis, qgis-grass-plugin7, qgis-grass-plugin6, qgis-grass-plugin-common and install **qgis-rel-dev** instead which will also install GRASS 7 because it has the grass plugin bundled up with it.

Then launch **QGIS Desktop x.x.x with GRASS x.x.x (Nightly)** from the start menu.

This is a nightly build of the release branch for QGIS with current patches and fixes.

Comment: cool, added an enhancement request https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/519

Comment: Hope you don't mind, edited your answer with another alternative.

Comment: Running QGIS 2.18.13 on win ... downgrading to grass 7.2.1 (from 7.2.2) following the first part of this answer provides a fix.

Comment: This usually happens after every GRASS update until the next QGIS point release. I don't suggest to install the dev version because it may fail due to newly introduced features/bugs.