# Creating centerline from lines using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, line

How do I create a centerline (vector data) from two parallel polylines (vector data) in QGIS?

For example, if the distances between two parallel lines are 14m, then I want to create a centerline at 7m from both lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GRASS has an add-on called [v.centerline](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/v.centerline.html).  Grass add-ons are a bit different to QGIS plugins.  To get GRASS add-ons working in QGIS see [How do I get grass plugin working in QGIS for Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214159) or search this site further for more info as 'how to install QGIS add-pns in QGIS' has been asked here a few times from memory.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a kind of polygon, you can use the new plugin by installing 'geosymplification'. After installing the ZIP file of geosymplification, choose the chordal axis on geosymplification.